# Problema con tabla responsive

Tags: html, css

Estoy armando una plantilla de email responsive. Cuando lo veo en escritorio (max 600px) la plantilla tiene 1 o 2 columnas, y al verse en moviles las partes de 2 columnas pasan a ser 1. El problema es que en una de las columnas debo meter 2 imagenes de diferentes proporciones y me quedan desproporcionadas. Adjunto foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deberia quedar asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el codigo online aca: coroleu.com/dev/email/email2.html

HTML

```css
html,
        body {
         margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }


        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }


        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin:0 !important;
        }


        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }


        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto;
        }

 
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }

        *[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }


        .x-gmail-data-detectors,
        .x-gmail-data-detectors *,
        .aBn {
            border-bottom: 0 !important;
            cursor: default !important;
        }


        .a6S {
         display: none !important;
         opacity: 0.01 !important;
        }

        img.g-img + div {
         display:none !important;
     }


        .button-link {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) { /* iPhone 6 and 6+ */
            .email-container {
                min-width: 375px !important;
            }
        }
                .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #555555 !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
                margin: auto !important;
            }

            .fluid {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }

            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }


            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

   .email-container p {
    font-size: 17px !important;
    line-height: 22px !important;
   }
   
        }
```

```html
   <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">
    <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="stack-column-center">
      <a href="tel:1147032722">
       <img src="imagen-pie-izq.jpg" aria-hidden="true" width="600" height="" alt="alt_text" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;" class="g-img">
      </a>
     </td>     
     <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="stack-column-center">  
      <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" width="300" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="300" style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">
       <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
         <a href="http://www.google.com">
          <img src="imagen-email.jpg" aria-hidden="true" alt="alt_text" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;" class="g-img">
         </a>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
         <a href="http://www.google.com">
          <img src="imagen-pie-der.jpg" aria-hidden="true" alt="alt_text" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;" class="g-img">
         </a>
        </td>    
       </tr>       
      </table>      
     </td>    
    </tr>    
   </table>
```

El problema es solo con esa columna. Entiendo que con las media queries se ajusta en los diferentes dispositivos, pero necesito saber como puedo distribuir esa columna para adaptar las 2 imagenes dentro de esa celda. Gracias.

Comment: Deberías de agregar el código relevante aquí para que si un día el link se rompiera, la pregunta no careciera de validez.

Comment: Ahi agregue el codigo, espero les sirva.

Comment: Una solución fácil es editar las imágenes y poner las 2 imágenes del mismo ancho y alto; esto a su vez se adaptará bien en móvil. Saludos

Comment: Fue lo que termine haciendo, usando 2 imágenes del mismo tamaño. Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres puedes hacerlo con las etiquetas @media, con ella puedes limitar como se verán las cosas dependiendo de las especificaciones de la pantalla, como la anchura. Te dejo un link de la documentación, en el encontraras toda la información para poder usar estas etiquetas.

Un ejemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
    ul li a {
        padding-left: 30px;
        background: url(email-icon.png) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) {
    ul li a:before {
        content: "Email: ";
        font-style: italic;
        color: #666666;
    }
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Ya lo se, en el codigo estoy utilizando media queries, el problema es como darle las proporciones adecuadas a las 2 imagenes para que se adapten a la cela de la derecha. Gracias

Comment: pues lo unico que se me ocurre es hacer varias versiones cambiando la relacion de aspecto, una un poco mas cuadrada y otra rectangular y aplicarlas como fondo a la celda y que se expanda. Siempre que mantengan la misma relacion de aspecto no se tendria que deformar mucho.